# Colorspace colours not visible in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, colorspace

I am trying to make my pdf suitable for printing as well. To do so, I use the `colorspace` package. Obviously, [the colorspace documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/colorspace) is available.

As usual, I define my colors, this time using `definespotcolor`, then I continue to use them normally, e.g. in `tikz`.
However, the new colors seem not to be used by tikz, which the following MWE demonstrates:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{colorspace}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \definespotcolor{blue}{HKS 44 K}[cmyk]{1,0.5,0,0}


    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[draw=gray, fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
            \node[anchor=south, color=blue] (B) at (0.5,1){blue};
            \draw[draw=gray, fill=lime] (2,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
            \node[anchor=south, color=lime] (B) at (2.5,1){lime};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

The expected outcome is the word 'blue' in blue above a blue-filled square, and the word 'lime' in lime above a lime-filled square. This is the output I get instead:
[image: unexpected outcome]

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this an incompatibility between `tikz` and `colorspace`?

P.S: Perhaps someone with more reputation than me could add the tag 'colorspace'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reason that I don't see tikz sometimes use `\colorlet[named]` and this breaks with colorspace. If one redefine the pgf command it works again:

```
 \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{colorspace}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfutil@colorlet#1#2{\colorlet{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
    \definespotcolor{blue}{HKS 44 K}[cmyk]{1,0.5,0,0}


    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[draw=gray, fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
            \node[anchor=south, color=blue] (B) at (0.5,1){blue};
            \draw[draw=gray, fill=lime] (2,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
            \node[anchor=south, color=lime] (B) at (2.5,1){lime};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. However, as I am offloading these color definitions into a custom package, this would mean my custom package should load ``tikz`` beforehand, right?

Also, I noticed when using ``colorspace`` I can no longer use ``\selectcolormodel{cmyk}``.

So after all, your's is a good answer, but it's not useful to me.

Comment: you can use \selectcolormodel{cmyk} if you disable the color conversion. But beside this there are a number of incompabilities.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I didn't find a documented option to disabled the color conversion, would you kindly point me to it? It is probably best for me though to not rely on ``colorspace``, until it is more evolved.

Comment: `\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
  \convertcolorsUfalse
  \convertcolorsDfalse`. And I don't think that colorspace will evolve much more, the problems you get show that its way to hook into xcolor is not very stable. The goal is to use l3color, but for this pgf will have to adapt too.

Comment: This sounds like a great roadmap. Thank you for pointing me rowards ``l3color``. I can't wait to see a functional ``l3color`` package with support for ``tikz`` and ``pgf``.

Answer (score 2):

Not related, but I recommend to avoid redefining existing colours and prefer using a custom name (here `myblue`).
I don't really understand why it does not work as is, but if you use the `fill` command instead of the `draw` one, it works...

[image: myblue]

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{colorspace}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \definespotcolor{myblue}{HKS 44 K}[cmyk]{0.5,0.5,0,0}


    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[myblue, draw=gray] (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
            \node[anchor=south, color=myblue] (B) at (0.5,1){blue};
            \draw[draw=gray, fill=lime] (2,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);
            \node[anchor=south, color=lime] (B) at (2.5,1){lime};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I see, why you don't suggest redefining existing colours. However, this is going to be for a package which acts as a corporate design, so I redefine the existing colours on purpose,, such that existing older publications will still work using the new corporate colours. Also, this makes it harder for users to accidentally use the wrong tints.
Of course, having it wotk with fill is a nice workaround for the compiled pdf, however, as stated, I need older code to work mostly without manual changeup, so I'd prefer to find a solution for ``\draw`` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there could be more than one incompatibility between `colorspace` and Ti*k*Z, as you can see if you search for related topics on TeX-SX. I'm not sure you would be able to construct a strong package using it. Maybe you could dig into its code and rewrite properly the coulour defitnitions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after doing more research on this, there is a bug in the `colorspace` package, which is also adressed in [this issue on github](https://github.com/jbezos/colorspace/issues/8).

Unfortunately, until this is resolved, I myself will cease from using the `colorspace` package, which also means to not use HKS colors in the meantime.

Consequently, to answer my own question: I set up everything as intended, however, the package is incompatible with **certain** `tikz` commands, e.g. `\draw`.

For single appliances, where a workaround is suitable and spot colours have to be used at all cost, the workaround provided  in the answers by @SebGlav and @UlrikeFischer might be acceptable.